# How to store results from a for loop in a data frame and export to Excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on writing a Python program that retrieves all file names and their modified date in a specific folder and then exporting that list to Excel. I have been able to do the first part (retrieve file names and modified dates from a folder). I am having a lot of trouble storing the results (all the file names + dates) in a data frame. I'm trying to get the results in a data frame because it's my understanding that you need to have it in one before exporting to Excel.

The below program almost gives me what I need but the data frame is only being created from the last record of the loop.

```
path = 'Insert Path'

def ts_to_dt(ts):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)

for file in os.scandir(path):
    if (file.name.endswith(".pdf") or file.name.endswith(".PDF")):
        results = {'FileName':file.name, 'DateModified':ts_to_dt(file.stat().st_atime)}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=results,index=[0])
print(df)
```

I'm sure there is something obvious that I'm missing, but I am new to Python so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `results` variable is getting reinitialized in every iteration of the loop, rather than you adding items to it. That is why you are getting only the last record. You can declare `results` outside of the loop and then append to those. Then, exporting to excel is easy!

```
path = 'Insert Path'

def ts_to_dt(ts):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)

results = {'FileName': [], 'DateModified': []}
for file in os.scandir(path):
    if (file.name.endswith(".pdf") or file.name.endswith(".PDF")):
        results['FileName'].append(file.name)
        results['DateModified'].append(ts_to_dt(file.stat().st_atime)
        

df=pd.DataFrame(data=results,index=[0])

# export it to excel:
# first argument is the output excel name (can include a path)
# second argument is what you want the sheet to be named.
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', 'sheetname')
```